# problemas con key

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

tengo este codigo en el cual es una tabla pero me han echo una observaciones que debo realizar pero no se como, esto que estoy haciendo es en storybook por si lo ven diferente aun compoente normal, creo que asi seria

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export function Table({ header, content }) {
  return (
    <table className="text-sm">
      <thead className="h-3" style={{ background: "#F1F1F1" }}>
        <tr className="h-3 border-b" style={{ borderColor: "#E0E0E0" }}>
          {header.map((head, index) => (
            <th key={index} className="px-3 py-3 font-light text-left">
              {head}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {content.map((row, index) => (
        <tr
          className="h-3 border-b"
          key={index}
          style={{ borderColor: "#E0E0E0" }}>
          {row.map((cell, i) => (
            <td className="px-3 py-3" key={i}>
              {cell}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  )
}

Table.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.string,
  header: PropTypes.array,
  content: PropTypes.array
}
export default Table
```

y me han echo dos observaciones las cuales son:

No se puede usar el indice como key para el componente genera problemas con el padre directo "row"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien me pudiera ayudar a corregir este error?

Comment: Si queires borrar una pregunta, ***BORRA LA PREGUNTA, NO ELIMINES SOLO SU CONTENIDO***, puesto que cualquiera puede ver la pregunta aun en el historial de ediciones... Si no puedes borrarla y realmente tienes problemas por haber publicado código que no deberías (Nunca jamás se debe poner código del trabajo en ningún sitio online!), pide a un moderador que lo haga

Comment: no puedo eliminarla, pero ya mande un mensaje

Comment: Por favor, no vandalizes la pregunta, ya que si tenia codigo propietario (Que no lo parece, porque la respuesta que te dieron anteriormente tenia un codigo similar), bastaba con anonimizar el mismo para que no fuera mas propietario y listo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te respondo porque veo que te has basado en la contestación que te he dado a una pregunta anterior :). Como bien te han comentado, no es una buena idea usar como `key` el índice del `map` si los datos pueden cambiar. Según la [documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) de react:

> No recomendamos usar índices para keys si el orden de los ítems puede
> cambiar. Esto puede impactar negativamente el rendimiento y puede
> causar problemas con el estado del componente. Revisa el artículo de
> Robin Pokorny para una explicación en profundidad de los impactos
> negativos de usar un índice como key. Si eliges no asignar una key
> explícita a la lista de ítems, React por defecto usará índices como
> keys.

En este caso tienes una tabla por lo que, efectivamente, no sería recomendable usar el índice como key ya que los datos entiendo que podrían cambiar (añadir o eliminar filas, por ejemplo).

Aquí tienes dos opciones:

1. Utilizar un identificador único que venga en tus datos. Un `id` o algo similar (como una combinación de varios campos) que sepas que **siempre va a ser único** y **no se va a poder modificar**.
2. Generar un identificador único. Existen librerías como [react-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-uuid) que te generan un id único. Puedes comentarlo con tus compañeros y ver si esto es una solución (o preguntar si ellos ya tienen una solución estándar para este tipo de casos).

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda man